# Exchange New-MailboxExportRequest PST backup to Linux server share

Tags: linux, windows, backup, exchange, outlook

I'm putting together a backup script for an MS Exchange server. It uses `New-MailboxExportRequest` to export the Mailbox as PST files.

However, it doesn't appear possible to write these PSTs to a Linux samba share (i.e a shared folder on a Linux server that's mounted in Windows).

Despite the share even having **777** permissions, `New-MailboxExportRequest` is unable to write to it. If I write to the folder using any other method from Windows, it's fine.

I understand the target folder needs write access by the *"Exchange Trusted Subsystem"* user. However, that user isn't available under the share folder permissions from Windows to grant access there (It only allows the linux server location to look for users/groups to add). I've already granted *"Full Control"* to the *"Everyone"* user/group and even that doesn't work... For all normal purposes, the folder is writeable.

Is there some way to specify access for *"Exchange Trusted Subsystem"* to a Linux folder share, or some other option here?

Alternatively, I may need to backup to an NTFS filesystem somewhere in the Windows end, but I'd prefer to use the Linux server if possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a group (Exchange Trusted Subsystem) not a user.

If your samba share cannot find/add that AD group to the share and file level permissions there, it isn't going to work.

Alternative would be to export it to a folder on the Exchange server itself and then just move the PST file across the network to the Linux samba share using a logged in user that has permissions to do so.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think if I spent alot of time configuring Samba to allow assigning AD groups to Linux folders it might work that way. However, I've opted for the simpler approach to backup to a drive on the Windows server and then mount that from the Linux server (from where it's transferred/rsync'd to an offsite AWS backup server).